# CodeBehind does not know <asp:textbox control but knows all my other <asp: controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, controls

Cheers,

I have an ASP web form that loads four views: three Gridviews and a Detailsview. Very simply, the first view, Gridview1 is shown to users. All the other views are not .Visible. When the user selects a row from Gridview1, then Gridview2, Gridview3, and the Detailsview becomes visible, and the first Gridview1 becomes not .Visible.

This arrangement is all working perfectly. I've added some `<asp:label` controls as titles for my views so I can also make them .Visible and not .Visible as well. Also working perfectly.

Now I'm trying to add two `<asp:textbox` controls to build a search function. Again, I want to use the `<asp:textbox` control instead of `<input type="text" id="txtBadge" name="Badge ID">` so I can also control the .Visible attribute in the CodeBehind. but my `<asp:textbox` controls seem to be out-of-scope to the CodeBehind. For example, one of my textboxes is called txtBadge. When I type txtBadge in the Codebehind, I get the red squiggly line under it and errors like "The name 'txtBadge' does not exist in the current context".

There are literally hundreds of posts here and in other forums about this particular error, but there's also seemingly hundreds of reasons as well. So I'm hoping someone can help me bring the `<asp:textbox` controls into the scope of the CodeBehind.

Here is the ASP page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeFile="Junk2.aspx.cs" Inherits="CPITraining.Junk2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <style>
        .container {
            max-width: 1530px;
        }
        .niceLabels {
            margin:15px 0px 15px 0px;
            display:inline-block;
            font:normal 30px Arial;
        }
        </style>
<%-- TOP CONTAINER --%>
    <div class="container" style="width:1500px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                    <%-- EMPLOYEE GridView1 Window --%>
                        <asp:Label ID="EmplList" runat="server" CssClass="niceLabels">Employee Listing</asp:Label>
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBadge" runat="server" OnInit="txtBadge_Init"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLast" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
                    </div>
                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="badge_id" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" 
                        GridLines="Vertical" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BADGE_ID" HeaderText="BADGE_ID" SortExpression="BADGE_ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRSTNAME" HeaderText="FIRSTNAME" SortExpression="FIRSTNAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LASTNAME" HeaderText="LASTNAME" SortExpression="LASTNAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TITLE" HeaderText="TITLE" SortExpression="TITLE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="deptname" HeaderText="deptname" SortExpression="deptname" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Column1" />
                            </Columns>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                        </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<%-- BOTTOM CONTAINER --%>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                        <%-- LEFT DETAILS VIEW --%>
                        <asp:Label ID="EmplHist" runat="server" CssClass="niceLabels">Employee History</asp:Label>
                        <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="badge_id" 
                         BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" 
                         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" Height="50px" Width="125px">
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <Fields>
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="BADGE_ID" HeaderText="BADGE_ID" SortExpression="BADGE_ID" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="FIRSTNAME" HeaderText="FIRSTNAME" SortExpression="FIRSTNAME" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="LASTNAME" HeaderText="LASTNAME" SortExpression="LASTNAME" />  
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="TITLE" HeaderText="TITLE" SortExpression="TITLE" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="deptname" HeaderText="deptname" SortExpression="deptname" />
                                <asp:BoundField DataField="Expr1" HeaderText="Expr1" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Expr1" />
                            </Fields>
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />  
                        </asp:DetailsView>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                     <%-- PROCEDURE CLASSES VIEW --%>
                    <asp:Label ID="ProcTraining" runat="server" CssClass="niceLabels">Procedure Training Records</asp:Label>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataKeyNames="badge_id" 
                     BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                     </asp:GridView>
                </div>
                <div class="row">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="row" style="background-color:#FFFFFF">
                     <%-- NONPROCEDURE CLASSES VIEW --%>
                    <asp:Label ID="NonprocTraining" runat="server" CssClass="niceLabels">NonProcedure Training Records</asp:Label>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" DataKeyNames="badge_id" 
                     BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
                     DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowPaging="True">
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<p>
    ///  various <asp:SqlDataSources, etc... 

</asp:Content>
```

Here's the CodeBehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;

namespace CPITraining
{
    public partial class Junk2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (GridView1.SelectedRow != null)
            {
                //when DETAILS are up
                DetailsView1.Visible = true;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
                EmplList.Visible = false;
                EmplHist.Visible = true;
                ProcTraining.Visible = true;
                NonprocTraining.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                //when MAIN list is up
                DetailsView1.Visible = false;
                GridView1.Visible = true;
                EmplList.Visible = true;
                EmplHist.Visible = false;
                ProcTraining.Visible = false;
                NonprocTraining.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string TrainingDBConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TrainingDBConnection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(TrainingDBConnection))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                StringBuilder sbCommand = new StringBuilder("Select * from XA_empmas where 1 = 1");
                if (txtBadge.Value.Trim != "")
                {
                    sbCommand.Append(" AND BADGE_ID=@txtBadge");
                    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@txtBadge", txtBadge.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
                if (txtLast.Value.Trim != "")
                {
                    sbCommand.Append(" AND LASTNAME=@txtLast");
                    SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@txtLast", txtBadge.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                }
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataSource = rdr;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Much thanks for any help!

Comment: In `Junk2.aspx.Designer.cs`, do you see field declarations for those two controls? What about the others, like `btnSearch` or `GridView1`?

Comment: Actually no @madreflection - thanks for responding so quickly. I see all my other controls in the same form like {protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView GridView1;} or {protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label EmplHist;}. Can I just add these lines myself? Or must they be auto-generated?

Comment: You can add them yourself. Just make sure they're marked `protected` like the rest (private won't work). That's how the `.aspx` file (a derived class) is able to access them. If you're using the designer, though, it might work out better in the long run if you re-add the controls with that. It's up to you, though. Try it both ways and see which you like better.

Comment: That worked! Now it's complaining about not having a definition for a "value" and no extension method "Value". Do these textboxes need to be initialized first? (like "") and how would I do that?  And in the Page_Load?

Comment: That's because the control is a different type now. This one has a `Text` property instead.

Comment: Could I cast them as a different type in the designer? I'm trying to use the fields for data entry, then capture the data entered in the codebehind for a WHERE clause in an SQL statement.

Comment: Casting requires a reference conversion. There is none here. They used to be one of the controls in the `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` namespace, until you converted them to `asp:TextBox` controls. You have to declare them as `System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox` and use the properties of that type.

Comment: gotcha. It's not .Value, it's .Text. thanks again.